# How to align radio buttons with its corresponding labels in one line on html and css?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, alignment

I don't know why it keeps on showing up like this
[radio buttons not aligning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Dt0.png)

But on the other survey form I made it's not like this. It's supposed to be all the options are in one line and the labels are inlined with the radio buttons as well with a little spacing in between. This is the html code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&display=swap');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@700&display=swap');
    
    
    //*setting font size as 62.5%=10px for easier REM fontsize calculations*/
    html {
      font-size: 62.5%;
    }
    
    body {
      background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6d/25/f2/6d25f2bc9f8c59dc9d5fbab6809126f8.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    
    /*Space around the main title*/
    #heading {
      padding: 7px;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    #title {
      font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
      color: darkblue;
      font-size: 2rem;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    
    #description {
      font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
      color: darkblue;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 0px;
    }
    
    /*This is the main white box where the survey form is located*/
    #survey-form {
      width: 35%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 20px;
      padding: 5px;
      
    }
    
    #sub-title {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
      color: rgb(66, 7, 188);
      font-size: 1rem;
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      color: rgb(17, 20, 62);
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /*Settings of labels such as name, e-mail,*/
    label {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      color: rgb(17, 20, 62);
      font-size: 0.75rem;
    
    }
    
    
    ::placeholder {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.75rem;
    }
    
    #dropdown {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.75rem;
    }
    
    
    input, select, textarea {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
    } 
    
    select {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
```

```html
 
          <div id="heading">
            <h1 id="title"> atrovska Feedback Form        </h1>
            <p id="description"> Your appreciated feedback will improve our services further. </p>
          </div>
          <form id="survey-form" class="survey-form">
            <label id="name-label">Name
            </label><br> 
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required></label><br>
            <label id="email-label">Email
            </label><br> 
            <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your Email" required></label><br>
        <label id="number-label">Phone Number
            <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter phone number used in transactions" required max="1" min="5"></label> <br>
        <label id="number-label">Order Number
            <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Enter order number used in any orders" required max="1" min="5"></label> <br>
          <label id="country-label"> Residence Country<br><select name="services" id="dropdown">
            <option id="country-placeholder" value="  " selected>Select a country</option>
            <option value="--">Not Specified</option>
            <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
            <option value="AO">Angola</option>
            <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
            <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
            <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
            <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
            <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
            <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
            <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="BT">Bhutan</option>
            <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
            <option value="BA">Bosnia and Herzegowina</option>
            <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
            <option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option>
            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
            <option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
            <option value="BN">Brunei Darussalam</option>
            <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
            <option value="BI">Burundi</option>
            <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
            <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
            <option value="CF">Central African Republic</option>
            <option value="TD">Chad</option>
            <option value="CL">Chile</option>
            <option value="CN">China</option>
            <option value="CX">Christmas Island</option>
            <option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
            <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
            <option value="KM">Comoros</option>
            <option value="CG">Congo</option>
            <option value="CD">Congo, the Democratic Republic of the</option>
            <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
            <option value="CR">Costa Rica</option>
            <option value="CI">Cote d'Ivoire</option>
            <option value="HR">Croatia (Hrvatska)</option>
            <option value="CU">Cuba</option>
            <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
            <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
            <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
            <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
            <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
            <option value="TP">East Timor</option>
            <option value="EC">Ecuador</option>
            <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
            <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
            <option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option>
            <option value="ER">Eritrea</option>
            <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
            <option value="ET">Ethiopia</option>
            <option value="FK">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
            <option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option>
            <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="FX">France, Metropolitan</option>
            <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
            <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
            <option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option>
            <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
            <option value="GM">Gambia</option>
            <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
            <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
            <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
            <option value="GR">Greece</option>
            <option value="GL">Greenland</option>
            <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
            <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
            <option value="GU">Guam</option>
            <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
            <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
            <option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option>
            <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
            <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
            <option value="HM">Heard and Mc Donald Islands</option>
            <option value="VA">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
            <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
            <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
            <option value="IN">India</option>
            <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="IR">Iran (Islamic Republic of)</option>
            <option value="IQ">Iraq</option>
            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
            <option value="IL">Israel</option>
            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
            <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
            <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
            <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
            <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
            <option value="KI">Kiribati</option>
            <option value="KP">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
            <option value="KR">Korea, Republic of</option>
            <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
            <option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option>
            <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
            <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
            <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
            <option value="LR">Liberia</option>
            <option value="LY">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
            <option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option>
            <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
            <option value="MO">Macau</option>
            <option value="MK">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
            <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
            <option value="MW">Malawi</option>
            <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
            <option value="ML">Mali</option>
            <option value="MT">Malta</option>
            <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
            <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
            <option value="MR">Mauritania</option>
            <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
            <option value="YT">Mayotte</option>
            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
            <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
            <option value="MD">Moldova, Republic of</option>
            <option value="MC">Monaco</option>
            <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
            <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
            <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
            <option value="MM">Myanmar</option>
            <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
            <option value="NR">Nauru</option>
            <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
            <option value="NC">New Caledonia</option>
            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
            <option value="NE">Niger</option>
            <option value="NG">Nigeria</option>
            <option value="NU">Niue</option>
            <option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option>
            <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
            <option value="OM">Oman</option>
            <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="PW">Palau</option>
            <option value="PA">Panama</option>
            <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
            <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="PE">Peru</option>
            <option value="PH">Philippines</option>
            <option value="PN">Pitcairn</option>
            <option value="PL">Poland</option>
            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
            <option value="RE">Reunion</option>
            <option value="RO">Romania</option>
            <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
            <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
            <option value="KN">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option> 
            <option value="LC">Saint LUCIA</option>
            <option value="VC">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
            <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
            <option value="SM">San Marino</option>
            <option value="ST">Sao Tome and Principe</option> 
            <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="SN">Senegal</option>
            <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
            <option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option>
            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
            <option value="SK">Slovakia (Slovak Republic)</option>
            <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
            <option value="SO">Somalia</option>
            <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
            <option value="GS">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
            <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="SH">St. Helena</option>
            <option value="PM">St. Pierre and Miquelon</option>
            <option value="SD">Sudan</option>
            <option value="SR">Suriname</option>
            <option value="SJ">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
            <option value="SZ">Swaziland</option>
            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="SY">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
            <option value="TW">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
            <option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option>
            <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
            <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
            <option value="TG">Togo</option>
            <option value="TK">Tokelau</option>
            <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
            <option value="TT">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
            <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
            <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
            <option value="TC">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
            <option value="TV">Tuvalu</option>
            <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
            <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="US">United States</option>
            <option value="UM">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
            <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
            <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
            <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
            <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
            <option value="VN">Viet Nam</option>
            <option value="VG">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
            <option value="VI">Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
            <option value="WF">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
            <option value="EH">Western Sahara</option>
            <option value="YE">Yemen</option>
            <option value="YU">Yugoslavia</option>
            <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
            <option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
            <label id="radio-label">Status of Order Number entered
            <input type="radio" name="provider" value="delivered">Delivered
            <input type="radio" name="provider" value="shipping">Shipping
            <input type="radio" name="provider" value="pending">Pending
              </label>
            
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to achieve that with the least efford is the use of `CSS-Grid`. for that apply to the wrapping element: `display grid; grid-template-columns: auto min-content`

That will move the radio button to the right side of the container and the labels will remain at the elft side of the container.

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto min-content;
}

/* for styling purpose only */
form {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="a">Element A</label>
  <input type="radio" id="a">
  <label for="b">Ele. B</label>
  <input type="radio" id="b">
  <label for="c">Large Element C</label>
  <input type="radio" id="c">
  <label for="d">E. D</label>
  <input type="radio" id="d">
  <label for="e">Larger Element E</label>
  <input type="radio" id="e">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on some of my forms.  I did a little more research and found a solution that worked.  Set a fixed width to the radio input and label, set the label to display inline-block and set the radio and label container, in this case span.wpcf7-list-item to display block. You may need to set the width to 100% so they will display vertically.  Hope this helps.

```css
span.wpcf7-list-item {
    display: block;
}
div.wpcf7 form label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}
input[type=radio] {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form id="someform">
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item first">
    <input type="radio" name="ftr" value="Yes" tabindex="">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Yes</span>
  </span>
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item last">
    <input type="radio" name="ftr" value="No" tabindex="">
    <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">No</span>
  </span>
</form>
```